# LeakCanary investigation : com.motorola.pixelpipe.PixelPipeTarget.mContext

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

With LeakMemory I constantly have a report on `com.motorola.pixelpipe.PixelPipeTarget.mContext`. I have no idea what this is. Does anyone have the same report ?

Using MotoX 2014 with 5.0

```
LeakCanary  D  In net.ebt.appswitch:0.8.3.394:3940002.
            D  * net.ebt.appswitch.activity.AppSwapActivity has leaked:
            D  * GC ROOT com.motorola.pixelpipe.PixelPipeTarget.mContext
            D  * leaks net.ebt.appswitch.activity.AppSwapActivity instance
            D  * Reference Key: 41a91591-b7f4-4a12-b077-46b35a53f9cf
            D  * Device: motorola motorola XT1095 victara_tmo
            D  * Android Version: 5.0 API: 21
            D  * Durations: watch=5028ms, gc=187ms, heap dump=1626ms, analysis=26686ms
```

Comment: I've noticed the same type of leak on my Moto X 2013 with 4.4.4. It probably needs to be added to the list of known leaks.

Comment: Ok, I would also add this leak is not really a leak on my end, for me it disappear after few seconds. But LeakCanary trigger before.